Sort execution of "Test Suites" in the Robot Framework
I need to determine the order in which my Test Suites run. In a given process, I need Suite X to run before Suite Y. Structure:

I'm using the Robot Framework in conjunction with Poetry.
In all the research I have done, the suggested is to use Pabot, which is usually used for parallelism. It seems that it should be able to determine the order of execution of tests, but it didn't work. I would like an alternative solution to the use of this library.

Needing to run one test or set of tests before another is a code smell. What's the cause of this dependency?

I have a Test Suite that fetches X data, imported by a previous Test Suite. Instead of creating a large Suite Setup, I mapped another page (Page Objects) to import the necessary data into the next Test Suite.

pabot with --ordering argument can be used order your execution even when not running anything parallel

One long time known trick (this feature) is to rename the test suites with a numeric prefix followed by two underscores. There is a feature in RIDE that hides these prefixes, and they are also not printed in the Log and Report (at Test Suite Directory level).
In your case you could have:
tests
     --> 01__Collection Suites A
        --> 01__Suite X.robot
     --> 02__Collection Suites B
        --> 02__Suite Y.robot



By default if given a directory, the framework will run the suites in it in alphabetical order.
Given your example suite X will run first because it is in a directory "collection suites A", coming before "suites B".
I suspect your files' names are different, as otherwise you'd get the result you wanted as a side effect, so rename them/their directories to achieve what you wanted.
A more solid approach would be to pass explicitly the order you want when running them - pass first the one you want to start first, then the second and so on.
robot "collection suites A/Suite X.robot" "collection suites B/Suite Y.robot" etc


Disclaimer - having dependency between suites is not optimal design; having such between cases is hardly acceptable, what to say b/n suites.

I imagined that it would not be ideal. It turns out that I need to import certain data and this action can be performed per user, so I created a Test Suite for that. In the next Test Suite I need to search for data that curiously are imported by the previous Test Suite, because I need to ensure that I will always search for the product "ProductNameX" regardless of the environment/base. That is why it is necessary to import. So I thought, Do I set this action as Suite Setup and do I do all the heavy import again, or do I just order it? That's how I came up with this solution.
